# Black dead area above app activity since Android 11

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-sdk-tools, android-11

Since Android 11, a large black area appeared above my app. I use multiple different activities (mostly RelativeLayout) and all of them are affected, so I don't think it's a layout issue. Switching between ActionBarActivity and AppCompatActivity or changing the SDK or build tools version also didn't affect the black space.

Settings:

- compileSdkVersion 29
- buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
- minSdkVersion 14
- targetSdkVersion 29
- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0

Does anyone know how to fix this or have a similar problem?

[image]

Comment: 1. What theme do you use for your activity? I use themes that extends 'Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar' or 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'. Both of them runs well in samsung android 11 devices. 

2. Does this happen to your physical device too? Or is it just the emulator? If you haven't tried out yet, trying it on a physical device may give you some clues.

Comment: I use Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, but the other themes have the same problem. Running the app on a physical device yields the same results, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

Add to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```html
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Which physical device did you use on your testing? I should also add these lines just in case.